# Static linked GDB cannot use HostName in target remote

Tags: gdb, static-linking, gethostbyname

The GDB is built on RHEL-4.7. I run the GDB on RHEL-6.3. If the GDB is dynamically linked, everything works OK. If the GDB is statically linked, I got

```
(gdb) target remote :2107
localhost: unknown host
:2107: No such file or directory.
```

When GDB is built statically, we got a warning message:

```
warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

I also searched with google, it seems that gethostbyname depends on the glibc library. I tried to install the compatible glibc library on RHEL-6.3. But there's no luck. Any hint?

Comment: Finally, figured it out. I have to turn the service "nscd" on.